# Android - How to make a background pattern combining bitmaps?

Tags: android, background, drawable

I know how to make a background pattern repeating a bitmap.
I also saw a way to combine two bitmaps using Canvas.
But I want to make a repeating bitmap in combination with a gradient drawable to make a background.
I have a .png file that it's partially transparent and I want to repeat it along with a gradient drawable (normal gradient XML).

This is the PNG: http://subtlepatterns.com/?p=1203

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use an XML bitmap to create a tile pattern:

```
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/my_png"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Then you should be able to use this as part of a [LayerList](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) drawable that also includes your gradient. Then use the layer list as the background drawable.